# NullPointerException on jnlp file execution

Tags: java, jnlp, linux-mint

I just installed JRE v7 and tried to run a jnlp file and getting the exceptions.

```
javaws s1384954682844.jnlp
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 61: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 96: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 61: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 96: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Nov 27, 2013 10:39:34 AM com.samsung.rtl.ClientBuilder reportVersion
INFO: BuildId: v2.1.2P-0-ged1fed2

Nov 27, 2013 10:39:37 AM com.googlecode.vfsjfilechooser2.utils.VFSResources <clinit>
INFO: Loaded i18n resources
Nov 27, 2013 10:39:38 AM org.apache.commons.vfs2.VfsLog info
INFO: Using "/tmp/vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
Nov 27, 2013 10:39:40 AM com.samsung.rtl.ClientConfiguration <clinit>
INFO: {SCREEN_SHOW_FPS=false, PREFIX=com.samsung.rtl.client#, SKIN_LOCATION=/afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/shari.dh/Downloads/skins}
Nov 27, 2013 10:39:40 AM com.samsung.rtl.Factory newSessionFactory
INFO: loaded sessionFactory com.samsung.rtl.DirmiFactory@14fcd9a
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getPermissions(JNLPClassLoader.java:1143)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPPolicy.getPermissions(JNLPPolicy.java:86)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPPolicy.implies(JNLPPolicy.java:182)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain.implies(ProtectionDomain.java:240)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:371)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getAccessControlContextForClassLoading(JNLPClassLoader.java:2179)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findLoadedClassAll(JNLPClassLoader.java:1522)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1554)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.AbstractStubSupport.remoteException(AbstractStubSupport.java:130)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession$StubSupportImpl.failed(StandardSession.java:2713)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.AbstractStubSupport.failedAndCancelTimeout(AbstractStubSupport.java:68)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession$Hidden$Admin$Stub$177.linkDescriptorCache(org.cojen.dirmi.core.StubFactoryGenerator)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession.<init>(StandardSession.java:440)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession.create(StandardSession.java:225)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.Environment.newSession(Environment.java:368)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.Environment$SocketConnector.connect(Environment.java:576)
        at com.samsung.rtl.DirmiFactory.connect0(DirmiFactory.java:54)
        at com.samsung.rtl.DirmiFactory.connect(DirmiFactory.java:44)
        at com.samsung.rtl.ClientConnector.bind0(ClientConnector.java:85)
        at com.samsung.rtl.ClientConnector.access$000(ClientConnector.java:40)
        at com.samsung.rtl.ClientConnector$1.doInBackground(ClientConnector.java:67)
        at com.samsung.rtl.ClientConnector$1.doInBackground(ClientConnector.java:64)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:291)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:330)
        at com.samsung.rtl.Workers$1.call(Workers.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at com.samsung.rtl.Workers.run0(Workers.java:69)
        at com.samsung.rtl.Workers.access$000(Workers.java:28)
        at com.samsung.rtl.Workers$2.doInBackground(Workers.java:62)
        at com.samsung.rtl.Workers$2.doInBackground(Workers.java:59)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:291)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:330)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getPermissions(JNLPClassLoader.java:1143)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPPolicy.getPermissions(JNLPPolicy.java:86)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPPolicy.implies(JNLPPolicy.java:182)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain.implies(ProtectionDomain.java:240)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:371)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getAccessControlContextForClassLoading(JNLPClassLoader.java:2179)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findLoadedClassAll(JNLPClassLoader.java:1522)
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1554)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.ClassLoaderResolver.resolveClass(ClassLoaderResolver.java:66)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.RemoteTypeResolver.resolveClass(RemoteTypeResolver.java:75)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.RemoteTypeResolver.resolveClass(RemoteTypeResolver.java:84)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession$ResolvingObjectInputStream.resolveClass(StandardSession.java:2185)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1609)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1480)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:696)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1890)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
        at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:308)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1890)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.MarshalledRemote.readExternal(MarshalledRemote.java:64)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1834)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1793)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.InvocationInputStream.readObject(InvocationInputStream.java:188)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession$Hidden$Admin$Skeleton$249.linkDescriptorCache$1(org.cojen.dirmi.core.SkeletonFactoryGenerator)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession$Hidden$Admin$Skeleton$249.invoke(org.cojen.dirmi.core.SkeletonFactoryGenerator)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession.handleRequests(StandardSession.java:955)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession.readRequest(StandardSession.java:1033)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.core.StandardSession$Handler.accepted(StandardSession.java:1785)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.io.BasicChannelBroker.accepted(BasicChannelBroker.java:172)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.io.BasicChannelBrokerConnector$Broker$1.ready(BasicChannelBrokerConnector.java:203)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.io.PacketInputStream$1.run(PacketInputStream.java:417)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run0(ThreadPool.java:542)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread$1.run(ThreadPool.java:516)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.cojen.dirmi.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:514)
```

I tried to verify the Java  using the link http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
and it displayed ' We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser.'

However, the troubleshooting articles are windows and MAC platform specific. I am using Linux Mint 32bit.

Could this be an issue with my JRE?

Output from janela:

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for file:/afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/vypins.sha/Downloads/s1384954682844.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase + href 'http://img-developer.samsung.com/afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/vypins.sha/Downloads/s1384954682844.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'file:/afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/vypins.sha/Downloads/s1384954682844.jnlp'.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'client-web-2.1.2.jar'.
The resource download at client-web-2.1.2.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for client-web-2.1.2.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/). 2) *"Regards!
Shari"*  That's two lines of noise.  Leave it out of questions in future.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson- The result says Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file

Comment: XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase + href 'http://img-developer.samsung.com/afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/vypins.sha/Downloads/s1384954682844.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'file:/afs/.cpiv.com/techhome/vypins.sha/Downloads/s1384954682844.jnlp'.
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'client-web-2.1.2.jar'.
The resource download at client-web-2.1.2.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for client-web-2.1.2.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. Thanks!

Comment: Edit the output into the question, use code formatting on it.  JaNeLA produces a text report - check the menus.

Comment: Done @Andrew Thompson

Comment: BTW - AFAIR the `JNLPClassLoader` was for embedding an applet that would otherwise be free floating.  If that is the case, use the new way of doing it.